# Include item number when converting list to dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a list of items to a data frame and keep the item numbers with the new rows in the data frame.

I want to keep the first 6 rows of data for 1800 specimens but the data is returned as a list. When I convert the list to a data frame, I lose track of which rows came from which items due to some items not returning any data during the batch process, thus, not showing up in the new data frame. I pasted the data from the first 6 items in the list below.

-My workflow is as follows:

```
out <-lapply(out, head)

out

[[1]]
           ID sequencedescription             database           citation
1  MNAG563-08              COI-5P BOLD: Public Records BOLD Systems, 2016
2  MNAG564-08              COI-5P BOLD: Public Records BOLD Systems, 2016
3  IAWL696-09              COI-5P BOLD: Public Records BOLD Systems, 2016
4 LPOKD816-10              COI-5P BOLD: Public Records BOLD Systems, 2016
5  GMEM065-11              COI-5P BOLD: Public Records BOLD Systems, 2016
6 GMGSA075-12              COI-5P BOLD: Public Records BOLD Systems, 2016
  taxonomicidentification similarity
1             Lepidoptera          1
2             Lepidoptera          1
3             Lepidoptera          1
4             Lepidoptera          1
5             Lepidoptera          1
6             Lepidoptera          1
  specimen_country specimen_lat specimen_lon
1    United States       39.717          -78
2    United States       38.991      -77.235
3    United States        30.08      -97.167
4    United States        36.74       -95.95
5    United States      33.4156     -89.2606
6    United States      35.6859     -83.4986

...

[[5]]
           ID sequencedescription             database           citation
1   MEC818-04              COI-5P BOLD: Public Records BOLD Systems, 2016
2 RDLQE057-06              COI-5P BOLD: Public Records BOLD Systems, 2016
3  LNCB034-06              COI-5P BOLD: Public Records BOLD Systems, 2016
4 RDLQI742-09              COI-5P BOLD: Public Records BOLD Systems, 2016
5 RDLQI756-09              COI-5P BOLD: Public Records BOLD Systems, 2016
6 BBLSW607-09              COI-5P BOLD: Public Records BOLD Systems, 2016
  taxonomicidentification similarity
1             Lepidoptera          1
2             Lepidoptera          1
3             Lepidoptera          1
4             Lepidoptera          1
5             Lepidoptera          1
6             Lepidoptera          1
  specimen_country specimen_lat specimen_lon
1           Canada      45.3967      -75.849
2           Canada       45.465      -73.075
3    United States       34.768      -76.764
4           Canada      49.2417      -72.423
5           Canada      45.4998     -76.3522
6    United States       33.883      -96.821

[[6]]
NULL
```

-Then I convert to a dataframe

```
out_frame <- do.call("rbind", lapply(out, data.frame))
```

-Then write to an xlsx file and first tried to assign ID #1 to the first 6 rows, ID #2 to the next 6 rows, etc. but it doesn't line up since item 6 returns NULL.

Comment: `Filter(Negate(is.null), out)`

Comment: Your statement seems unnecessarily complicated. Instead of `out <- lapply(out, head)`   Try `out <- head(out)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using a list of data frames:

```
out <- list(
  data.frame(a=10:30, b=20:40),
  data.frame(a=10:50, b=20:60),
  NULL
)

out2 <- lapply(seq(along=out), function(i) {
  df <- out[[i]]
  if(!is.null(df)) df$ID <- i
  df
})

out_frame <- do.call(rbind, lapply(out2, head))

out_frame
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for these replies. I was able to try several things and found that setting  `stringsAsFactors = FASLE`  when reading in data and then using the `setNames` function to assign my original IDs before requesting the output worked great. Then converting the output to a dataframe and writing to xlsx had the original IDs retained in the first column.